# Search by regular expression not working in spring boot mongo repository method

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, repository

I am using mongo repository for POJOs and need to use regular expression to fetch some data.

```
class A {
    String str;
}
```

in controller,

```
String s = "/xyz";

repositoryA.findByStrLike(s + "/[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
```

Above call is not returning object with Str "/xyz/string" although it exists.

Comment: your regex is looking for alphanumeric data upper and lowercase

Comment: issue is above is not pulling objects of Class A with str = /xyz/abc which is what would be expected. So want to confirm if any thing wrong with code.